# filtrar por numero y contar total de filas codeigniter query builder

Tags: php, base-de-datos, codeigniter, querybuilder

Tengo este ejemplo en la vista en el que funciona correctamente:

```
$db      = \Config\Database::connect();
             $builder = $db->table('users');
             $usuarios = $builder->countAll();
```

Cuenta todos los usuarios que tengo en mi tabla usuarios.
Ahora deseo hacer lo siguiente -> contar todos los resultados de la columna user_accept de la tabla users (tabla de usuarios nombrada anteriormente) y que se filtren unicamente por el resultado 1 es decir todas las filas que tengan el valor 1 que se cuenten.

he tratado lo siguiente:

```
$db      = \Config\Database::connect();
             $builder = $db->table('users');
             $activos = $builder->select('user_accept')->where('user_accept'== 1);
             $cont_activos = $builder->countAll('$activos');
```

Pero no me funciona y da error, alguien sabe como hacer funcionar el query builder? gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar [la documentación](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data).

Comment: @Marcos la her evisado pero no me aclaro nada, soy algo novata. He tratadod e hacerlo igual pero no me funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando mal el `where`.

Intenta hacerlo así:

```php
$db      = \Config\Database::connect();
$builder = $db->table('users');
$builder->select('user_accept');
$builder->where('user_accept', 1);
$cont_activos = $builder->countAll();
```

---

Más info [Query Builder Class > Looking for Specific Data](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=countall#where)

Comment: muchisimas gracias!! no entendía cual era el error y eso que miré la documentación se ve que se me pasó por altoa costumbrada al sql normal. Gracias!